# Counting groups of values by row

Tags: excel

I have a table with 2 columns:

A: number

B: "U" / "D" based on whether this current value in A is higher (U) or lower (D) than previous (lower) row

I am interested in counting sequential "D"s.
I'd like to add a column C that is perhaps able to indicate if the "D" in column B is single (then show "1") or is part of a group of D's (then indicate the length of the group).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: in `C1` use `=1*(B1="D")`, in `C2`: `=IF(B2="D",IF(B1="D",C1+1,1),0)` and drag it down. This formula would give you len of group for last "D" in group. Is it what you need?

Comment: Not quite. I would need the values in C to all represent the length the length of the group rather than just the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one in `C2`:

```
=IF(B2="D",IF(B1="D",C1,COUNTA(B2:INDEX(B2:B100,MATCH(1,1/(B2:B100<>"D"),0)-1))),0)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and drag it down.

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate if you explained to me why this formula needed to be "evaluated" first. When I tried simply dragging it down, it didn't work...

Comment: 1) enter formula in formula bar, 2) press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (instead just ENTER) - because it's array formula 3) drag formula down

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in B2, and that you're not going to get more than 50 consecutive Ds, try this formula:

```
=IF(OR(B2="U",B1="D"),"",COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B51,0,0,MATCH("U",B2:B51,0),1),"D"))
```

Increase B51 to B100 or more if you want more rows.

Comment: If my data starts in B2, why are you looking at the value of B1?

Comment: Do you have any Us in your column at all?

Comment: It checks the cell above to only put the count in the first Dcell of a group